# Sample groups and preserve row order

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe such as:

```
df <- data.frame(id = factor(c(12321,12321,12321,4445,4445,4445,4445,787,787,787)),
                 word = c("please", "stop", "that", "the", "fox", "jumps", "that", "please", "eat", "noodles"),
                 word_id = c(12,5,28,99,214,800,28,12,78,912))
```

And I am attempting to take a sample of the data frame while preserving the `id` group and the `word` and `word_id` order.

I tried `newDF <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% sample_frac(0.33)` but this takes a sample of each group.

I would like to result in a dataframe that takes a sample of all `id` groups in the original dataframe and preserves the order of the columns. So if I want to take a 33% sample of `df` I will end up with 33% of the `id` groups and the columns remain in order.

```
newDF <- data.frame(id = factor(c(12321,12321,12321,4445,4445,4445,4445)),
                    word = c("please", "stop", "that", "the", "fox", "jumps", "that"),
                    word_id = c(12,5,28,99,214,800,28))
```

Comment: Nest first: `df %>% nest(-id) %>% sample_frac(1/3)`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to alistaire's comment:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

newDF1 <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  sample_frac(1/3) %>% 
  unnest()

newDF2 <- anti_join(df, newDF1, by = "id")
```